# put filename in file between tags <fileName></fileName>

Tags: python, xml, sed, tags, filenames

After OCR-ing a few thousand TIFF images to ALTO XML I found out that the filename tag in the xml is empty. The xml file starts with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-0.xsd">
     <Description>
         <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
             <sourceImageInformation>
                  <fileName>                      </fileName>
             </sourceImageInformation>
```

I would like to process all xml files (recursively) and add the name of the tiff between the tags. The basename of the xml is the same as the tiff.
What would be the best method to do that? Should I use bash with find and sed or Python with string.replace, or are there better options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do *not* use string processing tools to process XML! XML is not a regular format, and using `str.replace()` or `sed` or any such tools is likely to lead to false positives and errors.

Use an XML parser; Python has [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which makes this task simple enough:

```
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

for xmlfile in Path("directory_with_xml_files").glob("*.xml"):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    namespace = tree.getroot().tag.partition('}')[0][1:]
    elem = tree.find(f".//a:fileName", {'a': namespace})
    elem.text = f"{xmlfile.stem}.tiff"
    tree.write(xmlfile, default_namespace=namespace,
               encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

The above processes all XML files in a given directory (using the [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), finding XML files using the [`Path.glob()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)). For each file, it parses the XML data into an XML tree, finds the first `<fileName>` element in the tree using a simple [XPath expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath), [updates the text](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) of that element (using the [filename stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem), which is the base name without the `.xml` extension) and writes out the XML tree back to the original file.

You stated you use an [ALTO schema](https://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/), which uses [XML namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) to distinguish between versions; the above should pick up the correct namespace to use from the root element, then uses that namespace (with `a` as the prefix) in the XPath query.

Demo:

```sh
$ mkdir demo
$ cat << EOF > demo/foo.xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-0.xsd">
>   <Description>
>     <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
>     <sourceImageInformation>
>       <fileName>                      </fileName>
>     </sourceImageInformation>
>   </Description>
> </alto>
> EOF
$ cp demo/foo.xml demo/bar.xml
$ cp demo/foo.xml demo/baz.xml
$ python3.7
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 19:45:08)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> for xmlfile in Path("demo").glob("*.xml"):
...     tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
...     namespace = tree.getroot().tag.partition('}')[0][1:]
...     elem = tree.find(f".//a:fileName", {'a': namespace})
...     elem.text = f"{xmlfile.stem}.tiff"
...     tree.write(xmlfile, default_namespace=namespace,
...                encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
...
>>> ^D
$ cat demo/*.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-0.xsd">
  <Description>
    <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
    <sourceImageInformation>
      <fileName>bar.tiff</fileName>
    </sourceImageInformation>
  </Description>
</alto><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-0.xsd">
  <Description>
    <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
    <sourceImageInformation>
      <fileName>baz.tiff</fileName>
    </sourceImageInformation>
  </Description>
</alto><?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-0.xsd">
  <Description>
    <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
    <sourceImageInformation>
      <fileName>foo.tiff</fileName>
    </sourceImageInformation>
  </Description>
</alto>
```

Comment: It works in your demo, but not in my files, which begin with: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-0.xsd">
        <Description>
                <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
                <sourceImageInformation>
                        <fileName>                      </fileName>
                </sourceImageInformation>

Comment: @Rene: that's because your XML is namespaced, you'd need to include that in the XPath expression: `.//{http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#}fileName`

Comment: I was struggling with namespaces using examples in https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html, but I'm stuck. Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: @Rene: I've updated the answer to pick up the namespace from the root tag.

Comment: @Rene: you found the lxml library, which is really great as that's the more powerful big brother of `xml.etree.ElementTree` with better XPath support. The `xml.etree.ElementTree` support for namespaces is more redimentary.

Comment: Why does it add "ns0:" to all the elements?

Comment: ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#") does that trick.

Comment: @Rene: I forgot to include the `default_namespace` argument to `.write()` at first, but have fixed that in the meantime.

Comment: @Rene: sure, putting it in the namespace registry as not having a prefix also works.

Comment: @Rene: I really prefer to use `default_namespace` here, *not* `ET.register_namespace()`; the latter is for widely recognized default namespace prefixes, not for default namespaces, really. The default namespace is a *per document choice*, the registry is a global affair, spanning all documents.

Comment: With the latest code I get the following error:
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 773, in write
    qnames, namespaces = _namespaces(self._root, default_namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 890, in _namespaces
    add_qname(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 868, in add_qname
    "cannot use non-qualified names with "
ValueError: cannot use non-qualified names with default_namespace option

Comment: @Rene: it means there are tags in your input document that don't have a namespace at all, so *at least one* element in your XML tree has no namespace whatsoever. Does that document have a `xmlns="..."` declaration on the root element, or is it using a prefix (so `<foo:alto xmlns:foo="...">`)?

Comment: @Rene: note that that's another (*strong*) argument against using `ET.register_namespace()` with an empty prefix: you are then *forcing* ElementTree to not use a prefix for namespaced elements, even if there are other elements in the tree that are unqualified (have no namespace at all). That in turn then can result in a broken XML document or the unqualified XML elements suddenly becoming qualified with a namespace, which would be very wrong indeed.

Comment: @Rene: I think the work-around here is to *not* set `default_namespace` for those documents. Use `try: tree.write(..., default_namespace=namespace)`, `except ValueError: tree.write(...)`, so try to write the document with a default namespace, and if that fails, fall back to using a namespace prefix.

Comment: The document starts with `<alto xmlns=`. I added it in my question

Comment: @Rene I can’t reproduce the problem with that document. I use the exact same start in the demo.